# Analysis critical point problem f:R->R

Tags: analysis

I'm struggling with proving this lemma but it seems so intuitively obvious, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has two continuous derivatives, has only one
critical point $x_0$, and that $f''(x_0) < 0$. Then f achieves its global maximum at
$x_0$, that is $f(x) \le f(x_0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f'$ is continuous. It has a unique $0$ at $x_0$. Since $f''(x_0)< 0$ the function $f'$ is decreasing around $x_0$. So just below $x_0$ you have $f'$  is positive and just above $x_0$ it is negative.

Now, as $f'$ is continuous and by the intermediate vlaue theorem you get that $f'$ is positive for all $x<x_0$ and $f'$ is negative for all $x > x_0$. So, $f$ is increasing for $x \le x_0$ and decreasing for $x \ge x_0$, which yields the claim.